# Pandas dataframe - transform selected cell values based on their suffix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a dataframe as below:

```
data_dict = {'id': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G2', 2: 'G3'},
 'S': {0: 35.74, 1: 36.84, 2: 38.37},
 'A': {0: 8.34, 1: '2.83%', 2: 10.55},
 'C': {0: '6.63%', 1: '5.29%', 2: 3.6}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

I want to multiply all the values in the data frame with 10000 (except under the column 'id' - 1st column) if they endswith %:

```
cols = df.columns[1:]
for index, row in df.loc[:, df.columns != 'id'].iterrows():
    for c in cols:
        if str(row[c]).endswith('%'):
            data_value = str(row[c])
            data_value = data_value.replace('%',"")
            df.at[index,c]= float(data_value) * 10000
```

Finally, this sets all the columns values (except the first column) to numeric:

```
df[cols[1:]] = df[cols[1:]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Is there a simple way to convert the values instead of iterating the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a custom function:

```
def pct_to_float(s, factor=10000):
    s2 = s.astype(str)
    m = s2.str.endswith('%')
    return (s.mask(m, pd.to_numeric(s2.str.rstrip('%'), errors='coerce')*factor)
             .convert_dtypes()
            )

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pct_to_float)

# to set the factor during the call
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pct_to_float, factor=10000)
```

Output:

```
   id      S        A        C
0  G1  35.74     8.34  66300.0
1  G2  36.84  28300.0  52900.0
2  G3  38.37    10.55      3.6
```

Comment: using custom function is helpful as i can reuse it with different factor, thanks..

Comment: @kitchenprinzessin yes, I like to do this when the process requires several transforms and when the function doesn't make the pipeline slower ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can select only the columns you need with:

```
df_tmp = df[["S", "A", "C"]]
```

Then use applymap:

```
df[["S", "A", "C"]] = df_tmp.applymap(lambda x: float(str(x)[:-1])*10000 if str(x)[-1] == "%" else float(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You rewrite the code by using `applymap`.